# Higher order polynomial fitting is not so handy surprisingly

Tags: matlab

I have a simple question but was not able to fix it by myself. I want to use the MATLAB curvefitting toolbox and fit higher order polynomials. It works if I want to fit polynomials of order 1 to 9. But, to my surprise it does not work for polynomials with degree higher than 9. To make it simple, can you just see the following simple code which does not work for me, unfortunately.

```
    l=1:0.01:10;y=l.^10;
[xData, yData] = prepareCurveData(l,y);
ft = fittype( 'poly10' );
[Fit, gof] = fit( xData, yData, ft, 'Normalize', 'on' );
```

Thanks in advance,
Babak

Answer (score 2):

It might be surprising, but it is documented: [List of Library Models for Curve and Surface Fitting](https://www.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/list-of-library-models-for-curve-and-surface-fitting.html).  You can always use `polyfit`, but as per the warning it issues, once you start getting polynomials of that degree, the fit is likely to be problematic anyway.

Answer (score 1):

**This answer is some supplement to the [Phil Goddard's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49967288/8960845).**

There is no `poly10` in the function `fit`.  But there are at least two alternative ways to fit any degree of the polynomial: something like `polyX`, where x could be 1,2,...,M, (if it is necessary).

```
clc; clear;
%%data
l=1:0.01:10;y=l.^10;
[xData, yData] = prepareCurveData(l,y);

%%High degree polynomial fitting
%set the degree of the polunomial
Degree=10;
%Fit with customize option
%generate the cell array from 'x^Degree' to 'x^0'
syms x
Str=char(power(x,Degree:-1:0));
%set the fitting type & options, then call fit
HighPoly = fittype(strsplit(Str(10:end-3),','));
options = fitoptions('Normalize', 'off','Method','LinearLeastSquares','Robust','off');
[curve,gof] = fit(xData,yData,HighPoly,options)
%Polyfit with the degree of Degree
p = polyfit(xData,yData,Degree)
```

But both `fit` and `polyfit` show some warnings, in my humble opinion, it is due to the [Runge's phenomenon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%27s_phenomenon), *which is a problem of oscillation at the edges of an interval that occurs when using polynomial interpolation with polynomials of high degree over a set of equispaced interpolation points.*

Discard the data in this situation or some similar ones, where the true function is polynomial with high degree, says something in the `Pn[R]`, high degree polynomial is not recommended in the fitting of the complex function.

**Edit: generalized the code.**

Comment: Note that the option of `Normalize` should be `off`, as `fit` will give wrong fitting parameters otherwise.

Comment: Thanks Hunter and Phil a lot!